# Issues with deleting a record from a GridView but not in the database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

I've created a Delete function which sets the "Status" of a GridView item to 0. The changes reflect in the SQL DB, however, the record still shows on the GridView. Here's my code for Delete:

```
    Protected Sub lbtnDeleteStaff_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles lbtnDeleteStaff.Click

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("SecurityDBConnectionString2").ToString())
        ' Create a command object.
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()

        ' Assign the connection to the command.
        cmd.Connection = conn

        ' Set the command text
        ' SQL statement or the name of the stored procedure 
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Personnel SET Status = 0 WHERE SempID = @SempID"

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SempID", xSelectedPersonID)

        ' Set the command type
        ' CommandType.Text for ordinary SQL statements; 
        ' CommandType.StoredProcedure for stored procedures.
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        ' Get the PersonID of the selected row.
        'Dim strSempID As String = gvPerson.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Text

        ' Append the parameter.
        'cmd.Parameters.Add("@SempID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = strSempID

        ' Open the connection.
        conn.Open()

        ' Execute the command.
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using

    ' Rebind the GridView control to show data after deleting.
    BindGridView()


End Sub
```

And here's my BindGridView function:

```
Private Sub BindGridView()
    ' Get the connection string from Web.config. 
    ' When we use Using statement, 
    ' we don't need to explicitly dispose the object in the code, 
    ' the using statement takes care of it.
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBConnectionString2").ToString())
        ' Create a DataSet object.
        Dim dsPerson As New DataSet()

        ' Create a SELECT query.
        Dim strSelectCmd As String = "SELECT SempID,EmpName,Position,PDNo,DateHired,ContactNo,Email,EmergencyContactNo,ContactPerson,DateQuitTerminated,Remarks FROM Personnel WHERE Status = 1"

        ' Create a SqlDataAdapter object
        ' SqlDataAdapter represents a set of data commands and a 
        ' database connection that are used to fill the DataSet and 
        ' update a SQL Server database. 
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, conn)

        ' Open the connection
        conn.Open()

        ' Fill the DataTable named  "Personnel" in DataSet with the rows
        ' returned by the query.new n
        da.Fill(dsPerson, "Personnel")

        ' Get the DataView from Security Personnel DataTable.
        Dim dvPerson As DataView = dsPerson.Tables("Personnel").DefaultView

        ' Set the sort column and sort order.
        'dvPerson.Sort = ViewState("SortExpression").ToString()

        ' Bind the GridView control.
        'gvPerson.DataSource = dvPerson
        gvPerson.DataBind()
        conn.Close()
    End Using
End Sub
```

I'm not quite sure what Ive missed in my code. I already set `Status=1`so shouldn't the GridView show just those records with 1? The GridView currently shows both records with Status 1 and 0. My goal is to have those with `Status = 0` disappear from the GridView but still on the DB. Thanks

Regards,

EDIT: Here's the code of the GridView. Towards the bottom of the code is where I set the SQLDataSource.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPerson" CssClass="EU_DataTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="SempID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="6" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="gvPerson_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPerson_PageIndexChanging" OnRowCommand="gvPerson_RowCommand">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="SempID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SempID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmpName" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="EmpName" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="PDNo" HeaderText="Badge Number" SortExpression="PDNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Position" HeaderText="Position" SortExpression="Position" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateHired" HeaderText="Date Hired" SortExpression="DateHired" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactNo" HeaderText="Contact Number" SortExpression="ContactNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmergencyContactNo" HeaderText="Emergency Contact Number" SortExpression="EmergencyContactNo" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="DateQuitTerminated" HeaderText="Termination Date" SortExpression="DateQuitTerminated" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ContactPerson" HeaderText="Contact Person" SortExpression="ContactPerson" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Remarks" HeaderText="Remarks" SortExpression="Remarks" />
                    </Columns>
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#54a1e5" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                </asp:GridView>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [SempID], [EmpName], [PDNo], [Position], [DateHired], [ContactNo], [Email], [EmergencyContactNo], [DateQuitTerminated], [ContactPerson], [Remarks], [Status] FROM [Personnel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the datasource to your gvPerson like this:

```
Dim datatable = dsPerson.Tables("Personnel")
gvPerson.DataSource = datatable 
gvPerson.DataBind()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for you response. I've tried that line of code however I get an error that states: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'gvPerson'.  Remove one definition.' I will edit my question and add the code to the GridView

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to fix my problem by adding  this line of code under my GridView:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecurityDBConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [SempID], [EmpName], [PDNo], [Position], [DateHired], [ContactNo], [Email], [EmergencyContactNo], [DateQuitTerminated], [ContactPerson], [Remarks], [Status] FROM [Personnel] WHERE ([Status] = @Status)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Status" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```